# Accessing the most recently archived version of a file checked in with svn

Tags: svn

I've posted this question on the [wandisco svn forum](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/linux-unix-servers/78017-accessing-the-most-recently-checked-in-version-of-files) but i doesn't seem to get much traffic, and nobody could answer the question, so I thought I'd try here.

Often I'm working offline, and want to look at the most recently archived version of a file that I've checked in with `svn`.

Under `svn` version 1.6, it was easy to do this; for example, the most recently checked in version of `myFile.tex` was stored as `.svn/text-base/myFile.tex.svn-base.`

In svn version 1.8, everything is different; `myFile.tex` is saved somewhere in `.svn/pristine`, but the filename has been converted to some impenetrable hexidecimal one, understandable only by svn, in this case: `53/5314d09a1fdbe26876fca60c088d992a25c7fb9d.svn-base`

I've tried using hex to text converters, but get garbage back.

Does anybody know if there's a way to unpack hexidecimal strings like this

Thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

1. "most recently checked in version..." means **nothing** in Subversion-lingua, you have to use commonly-accepted terms
2. In *most cases* SVN Working Copy isn't mixed, thus - you can to know only BASE revision of repo
3. Anyway, **good and version-independent** way for your task is `svn info PATH/TO/FILE`

> ```
> >svn info G2.txt
> ...
> Revision: 5
> ...
> Last Changed Rev: 2
> ...
> ```

I.e. - WC checkouted at rev. 5, last changes of file was performed at rev. 2

HTH

Comment: Thanks for this!   I just checked in 3 files, `a.tex`, `a.sty`, and `a.pdf`, to my repo, and there are now three files in `../.svn/pristine`, named       `d8/d883a3bad846b83092975e03fb79c8552594688f.svn-base`  
`d5/d5b5f2ac39db89f079bfc1b94f8e9e0367e67adf.svn-base`  
`35/355e64b3d3c0f00c8c8c4ed18b5a2cce81bc0d94.svn-base`     My question is, how do I tell which of these files is `a.tex`, which is `a.sty` and which is `a.pdf`.     Of course, I could to a trial and error test, with grep, but there has to be a more systematic way of doing this.

Comment: @LeoSimon - *Why* do you want to work with files in `.svn`?! And just note: in `.svn` you have **pristine copies** of chechouted files, see at **content** of files, forgot names

Comment: There are many reasons why I'd want to.  Worst case if I've erased the working copy by accident.    Or if I've made some mistake and now can't compile the file, I want to go back and compare with a copy that did compile.   Obviously if I have a network connection, I can rename the file and use `svn update`